# rspec / testing AR objects without reloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Using factory bot, creating variables like so :

```
let!(:deal) { create(:deal) }
```

The following sample :

```
expect {
  ...stuff that effectively associate an attachment to the deal...
}.to change { deal.attachments.length }.from(0).to(1)
```

does not pass.

The same test, while reloading the deal :

```
...to change { deal.reload.attachments.length } ...
```

does pass.

In frequent other occasions, I end up using this `reload` method. It feel like this is not the right way to go at all, and that i'm missing the point

What would be the correct way to test changes on records without having to reload them ?

Comment: It feels wrong, but I see this pattern a lot. The "reload" part takes some getting used to, but I find this pattern more readable than the alternatives.

Comment: well once you know exactly what's up (based on the answer below), it makes better sense not to use it imho

Comment: If you can avoid reloading, do! But what if you want to check that a field changed on an instance? It's helpful to have in your toolbox.

Comment: Well as it is explqined  here for length vs count, am pretty sirr there might be a way (or a workaround). I mean by that, all tutorials or documentation followed; 'reload' is never 'advertised' (as a way to go)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's talk about what's happening:

`deal.attachments` is queried twice, once before your `expect` block is invoked, and then once after, to compare the difference.

Because rails knows that costs to the database are expensive (performance-wise), it caches the values of `has_many` relationships to save on performance. So, the first time `deal.attachments` is called is the only time a database query is actually made. Add a `reload` forces a second database query, giving you the result you expect.

So, this boils down to "How do I make sure the database is queried each time?"

The method you're using is what I'd consider acceptable but there are some other options. The one I'd suggest is using [`count`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-count) instead of `length`.

> This will perform the count using SQL.

This guarantees that a SQL query will be made before and after your `expect` block is invoked.

```
expect {
  ...stuff that effectively associate an attachment to the deal...
}.to change { deal.attachments.count }.by(1)
```

Comment: perfect, that's the slight but meaningfull thing I was expecting!